# Why dose LogonUser(...) work for a invalid domain?

Tags: winapi, inno-setup

```
function TryLogonUser(ErrorCode: Longint): Integer;
var
  Token: THandle;
begin
  LoginOk := LogonUser(UserName, DomainName, Passwd, LOGON32_LOGON_NETWORK_CLEARTEXT,LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT50, Token);
  ErrorCode := DLLGetLastError;
  Log('SysErrorMessage('+IntToStr(ErrorCode)+')'+SysErrorMessage(ErrorCode));
  Log('LoginOk = '+IntToStr(LoginOk));
end;
```

When I using a valid local username and wrong domain name(localuser@wrongDomain), login fails, return 0,using a valid domain user name and wrong domain name(domainuser@wrongDomain), the login is successful, returns 1.why??